# Swift: selection of type specific method implementions defined in extensions?

Tags: swift

**Question:**

Is there any way to make Swift select a type specific override when called from a function in the base implementation?

**Context:**

I am trying to solve / work around another problem (that of Swift implementations of protocol methods not being visible if they are on generic classes), and I am trying to figure out how I might bridge the problem by delegating to closure arguments.

I was hoping I could use method implementations in type constrained class extensions to provide different implementations for different types of a given generic class.  What I am seeing though, is that the extension implementations are only used when the methods are called directly, and nto from within another method in the class.  Is there a work around for this, any other technique I can use?

```
class Fubar<T, U> {
    init() {
        doSomething()
        doSomethingDynamic()
    }

    func fromFunction() {
        doSomething()
        doSomethingDynamic()
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("Base implementation doSomething")
    }

    @objc dynamic func doSomethingDynamic() {
        print("Base implementation doSomethingDynamic")
    }

    @objc dynamic func callDirectly() {
        print("Base implementation of callDirectly")
    }
}

extension Fubar where U == String {
    func doSomething() {
        print("U is a string!")
    }

    func doSomethingDynamic() {
        print("U is a string!")
    }

    func callDirectly() {
        print("U is a String!")
    }
}

let fubar = Fubar<Int, String>()
fubar.callDirectly()
fubar.fromFunction()
```

**What I actually got:**

```
Base implementation doSomething
Base implementation doSomethingDynamic
U is a String!
Base implementation doSomething
Base implementation doSomethingDynamic
```

**What I was hoping for:**

I was hoping that the initializer would invoke the type specific override defined in the extension, instead of the generic base implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: Extensions can't be used to override methods. From the Swift book: *"Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality."*

Comment: Doesn't that apply to strictly overriding though - from a base class?  In this case, I get the expected result when I call the method externally, so the behavior is different.  If you could never override, then it would never work.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I would think class inheritance would be what you want here.